# Having trouble with the dropdown menu as its not appearing on hovering (just a html-css template)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble writing a code for a simple drop down menu but cant understand what I'm doing wrong still new to coding. Whenever I bring my cursor over the respective dropdown `li` tag the hover color effect is there but nothing comes down. In a previous attempt when the code was a a little different the list `id` appeared but it was in an `inline` manner and was align horizontally not vertically plz help.

[image: the output]

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#main {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display block;
}

#searchbar {
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li id="main"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="main"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li id="main"><a href="#">More</a>
        <ul class="c">
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article1</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article2</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article3</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="main"><a href="#">About US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <div id="searchbar"><input type="text" name="search" /><button id="button">GO</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the status of the question? If someone solved it, it would help everyone (including you) to mark it as solved.

Comment: Where to add the status?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have `id="main"` applied to multiple elements. `id` is meant to be unique and applied to only one element.

Second, your `hover` effect was just a little incomplete. See my changes below.

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
  height: 30px;
  /*overflow: hidden; don't do this if you want dropdowns */
}

#nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#main {
  display: inline;
}

#nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
}

#nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav>li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#nav>li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  bottom: -80px;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
}

#searchbar {
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a>
        <ul class="c">
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article1</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article2</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article3</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <div id="searchbar"><input type="text" name="search" /><button id="button">GO</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to target `ul li ul` which you will show and hide ... and #main id can not be duplicate on the same page.. working example as below

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: #9C9C9C;
  margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#main {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
}
ul li{display: inherit;}
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li ul li{display:block; list-style-type:none}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  z-index:1000;
  
}

#searchbar {
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li class="nestedchild"><a href="#">More</a>
        <ul class="c">
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article1</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article2</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article3</a></li>
          <li class="B"><a id="A">Article4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="main"><a href="#">About US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



  <div id="searchbar"><input type="text" name="search" /><button id="button">GO</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be like that.

```
.first .link {
color: black;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
width: auto;
border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
position: relative;
top: 0vh;
}
.first {
background: green;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
 }

.menu {
  background-color:red; 
 }

.bottom-line {
  border-bottom:5px solid pink; 
 }



 #navbar{

background-color: #9C9C9C;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px 0;
width: 1200px;


}
#nav{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: arial;
float: left;
list-style: none;
}
 #main{
  display: inline;
 }
 a{
   display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
 margin-top: 0px;
  }
  a:hover{
   background-color: #d3d3d3;
   color: black;
   }

  ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
    }   

 ul li ul {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   list-style: none;
  top: 32px;
   z-index: 5;
    background-color: #ddd;
  padding-left: 0;
  } 
  ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
  }

#searchbar {
   margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
 }
```

and You can also see demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/harry_2311/7dcgj0rw/1/)